# Seagate's 30TB NAS with SimplyRAID configuration

Tags: raid, seagate

I recently bought a Seagate NAS Pro 6-Bay 30TB Network Attached Storage Drive (STDF30000100) from Amazon ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LM6KVZA?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LM6KVZA)). It says it uses Seagate's SimplyRAID configuration. Unfortunately I could not find a clear explanation of how much space will I get if I opt for SimplyRAID as opposed to other RAID solutions. Can someone explain this to a newbie? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 30 TB is the gross disk space, six 5 TB disks.

In addition to the [JBOD and common RAID levels, SimplyRAID](http://www.seagate.com/manuals/network-storage/business-storage-nas-os/raid-modes/) sounds like a software solution that allows you to make maximum use of different sized disks while still maintaining a certain amount of redundancy, allowing you to lose 1 or 2 disks without losing your data.

- SimplyRAID single security with single-disk protection (sounds like RAID 5 and your effective storage space will be (N - 1) or 5 * 5 TB = 25 TB)
- SimplyRAID double security with double-disk protection (sounds similar to RAID 6 where your usable storage space will be (N - 2) or 4 * 5 TB = 20 TB)

My first guess would be that SimplyRAID is front-end to something similar to the Linux Volume Manager LVM and the [mirroring and striping options](https://serverfault.com/a/653296/37681) available there.

Comment: Excellent answer.